# Detecting All Caps in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble trying to write a regular expression in JavaScript that can detect a whole word of at least 2 characters that is typed in all CAPS.

This is what I have tried and it seems to work .

```
/\b[^\Wa-z0-9_]+\b/
```

however, I will detect if a user starts a string "I like you."

Since, I is capitalized it returns true, hence why I want to only detect words that are all caps of more then 2 letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var matches = ("hoi HOW are YOU doing?").match(/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/g);
console.log(matches);  // ["HOW", "YOU"]
```

Answer (score 6):

Your character group is needlessly complicated. If you simply want capital letters, why not use `[A-Z]`?

To restrict it to words of >= 2 letters, use `{2,}` instead of `+` as quantifier:

```
/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this as your regex:

```
/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/
```