# To Title Case / To Proper Case Unless Consecutive Caps Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where users input information, and this information is then displayed publicly on the site.  Since I can't trust users to input information correctly, I'm using javascript to correct their errors.  For instance, one of the fields requests that you enter a persons name in the following format (proper case):  First Name

I'm using the following function to turn their input into titlecase/propercase:

```
var firstname = [the value the person entered on the form as the first name]
function toTitleCase(str) { return str.replace(/wS*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});}
toTitleCase(firstname);
```

A problem I am experiencing, is when people are intentionally trying to use a series of all caps letters, like CFO or CPA (or some other acronym that requires all caps) in the same field.  For instance, if they put in: "first name CPA" the javaascript function turns that into "First Name Cpa" which is almost correct...but CPA needs to remain in all caps.

This is a brain teaser for me, as I can't figure out a solution.  Any help?  Whatever the solution is, it absolutely has to be a javascript solution, if you can come up with one at all.

Comment: I should note that I realize there is an easy method for making an entry in form "proper case" before storing it to the mySQL database, but for reasons I won't go into, let's just say it is too late for that...I'm stuck correcting the improperly capitalized entries client side & not server side.

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Uppercase all first chars regardless and don't touch the rest. However that will mess with last names with van, der, zum and other Germanic names that must remain lowercase. but added value is that you currently also mess up McDonald, O'Leary and such

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this will likely not be possible. The only solution that may work is having a list of words/phrases that should have specific capitalization settings. But it will also be difficult to catch the never ending list of names like McDonald. Therefore, it may be best just to not try to fix entries or simply manually review entries.

Comment: This was my gut reaction as well...and it's literally impossible to hardcode a bunch of specific things to not change.  What about enclosing things that should not be edited within a certain charcter...like "first name #CFO#" any ideas for using the same function but having it not change anything within the pound signs?

Comment: That could be a possibility, but you'll run into the reverse problem: that people will forget to enclose items in special characters, just as people forget to capitalize properly.

Comment: Haha, very true...alright, what about a regex that detects all caps words...is that headed in the right direction?  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255104/regex-to-match-all-caps-words-php

Comment: Better yet, same thing as my above comment, but done with javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654887/detecting-all-caps-in-a-string  Anyway you can think of to incorporate the two together?

Comment: That may work, but if someone types their name in all caps (which many older people do) it would not format it correctly... But, it is probably the closest solution possible.